# How can I find the 'average' of two columns of colors in R?

Tags: r, function, colors, purrr

I have a data frame of colors and I would like to find a way to create a third column. The third column should be comprised of a color that is a blend of the two other columns.  I have an example data frame and a function that I thought would do the trick. It uses R's `colorRampPalette()` function and `purrr::map2()`. However, this returns a listed column that when unlisted is identical to the first column in the dataframe.

```
# Create a function for colors

x <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(11, 'Spectral')

spectral_col <- colorRampPalette(x)

# Apply this function to 

tibble(first = sample(spectral_col(100)),
       second = sample(spectral_col(100))) %>% 
  mutate(middle.color = map2(first, second, function(x, y){
    k <- colorRampPalette(c(x, y))
    k(1)

  }))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just generate a palette of length `1`, it's always going to be the first value. 
As in:

```
colorRampPalette(c("#000000","#FFFFFF"))(1)
#[1] "#000000"
```

You need to generate at least 3 values to take the middle one between the two specified colours:

```
colorRampPalette(c("#000000","#FFFFFF"))(3)
#[1] "#000000" "#7F7F7F" "#FFFFFF"
colorRampPalette(c("#000000","#FFFFFF"))(3)[2]
#[1] "#7F7F7F"
```

You could also use `colorRamp` as an alternative if you want to specify more precise mid-points:

```
rgb(colorRamp(c("#000000","#FFFFFF"))(0.5), max=255)
#[1] "#7F7F7F"
```

With a hat-tip to r2evans, you can put this in your `purrr` function:

```
dat <- tibble(first = sample(spectral_col(100)),
       second = sample(spectral_col(100)))

dat %>%
  mutate(middle=map2_chr(first,second, ~rgb(colorRamp(c(.x,.y))(0.5), max=255)))
```

Or in base R's `mapply`:

```
mapply(function(x,y) rgb(colorRamp(c(x,y))(0.5), max=255), dat$first, dat$second)
```

Comment: Thanks for this; it's really helpful. I'm still having trouble applying it to all rows in the data frame.

Comment: Use `middle=map2_chr(first,second,~rgb(colorRamp(c(.x,.y))(0.5), max=255))`