# Is there a function that calculates an average of n Hex colours in R?

Tags: r, colors, hex, rgb

I have a df with samples as rows. Each has three variables that are different colours in Hex format. 
Is there a function to average these colours without converting it to rgb?

```
   id       x       y       z
1   0 #EE30A7 #EE30A7 #3D3D3D
2   1 #ED31A5 #EC30A5 #3D3E3C
3   2 #EC33A4 #EA30A4 #3E3F3C
4   3 #EB34A3 #E830A3 #3F413C
5   4 #EA36A2 #E630A2 #40423C
6   5 #E937A1 #E530A1 #41443C
7   6 #E8399F #E330A0 #42453C
8   7 #E83A9E #E1309F #43473C
9   8 #E73C9D #DF319E #44483C
10  9 #E63E9C #DE319D #45493C
```

To this df I want to add another col of the average colour.

Comment: Can you show first few expected average values?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886163/how-can-i-find-the-average-of-two-columns-of-colors-in-r/51886197

Answer (score 3):

I'll make an attempt at this, ugly as it may be:

```
rgb(t(Reduce(`+`, lapply(dat[c("x","y","z")], col2rgb))/3), maxColorValue=255)
# [1] "#B33483" "#B23582" "#B13681" "#B03780" "#B03880" "#AF397F" "#AF3A7E" "#AE3B7D" "#AE3C7D"
#[10] "#AD3D7C"
```

Essentially I'm using `col2rgb` to create a set of r/g/b matrices, which I then average across, and convert back to a hex string. I'm not sure if this meets your "*a function to average these colours without converting it to rgb*" requirement though.