# How perform weighted average of colours in R?

Tags: r, colors

I have the following dataset (dat.an) as a `.csv` file:

```
Animal,Bias,Colour
Frog,2,"#0000FF"
Frog,1,"#FFFFFF"
Dog,16,"#FFFFFF"
Cat,2,"#FF0000"
Frog,3,"#FF0000"
Cat,8,"#0000FF"
Dog,12,"#0000FF"
Cat,8,"#FFFFFF"
Cat,12,"#0000FF"
Dog,2,"#0000FF"
```

I want to group according to `Animal` and produce a single weighted average `Colour` where the weights are in the `bias` column.

I've managed to get as far as:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat.an %>%
  group_by(Animal)
```

there is no `as.colour` option for dealing with hex colours. So I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: There *is* such a function, but it's called `col2rgb`, not `as.colour`.

Comment: You need to define a (continuous) color scale which maps numeric values to colors.

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58055108/680068

Comment: The definition of what an "average" color is really depends on what color space you are using. Do you just want to average your R, G, and B values separately? Transformations in that color space don't always look nice.

Comment: I'm really going to need a bit more help with the code, please. Never realised averaging a colour can get so convoluted. How do palette mixers work? I just wanted a way to range the output between `red` and `blue` with white as the middle ground.

I am running into errors like ` colour intensity 1.13333, not in [0,1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df <- data.frame(Animal = c('Frog', 'Frog', 'Dog', 
                            'Cat', 'Frog', 'Cat', 'Dog',
                            'Cat', 'Cat', 'Dog'),
                 Bias = c(2, 1, 16, 2, 3, 8, 12, 8, 12, 2),
                 Colour = c('#0000FF', '#FFFFFF', 
                            '#FFFFFF', '#FF0000', '#FF0000', 
                            '#0000FF', '#0000FF', '#FFFFFF', 
                            '#0000FF', '#0000FF'))
library(tidyverse)
new_df <- df |>
  transmute(
            Animal = Animal,
            red = strtoi(substr(Colour,2,3),16),
            green = strtoi(substr(Colour,4,5),16),
            blue = strtoi(substr(Colour,6,7),16),
            weight = Bias
            ) |>
  group_by(Animal) |>
  summarise(
            red = sum(red * weight),
            green = sum(green * weight),
            blue = sum(blue * weight),
            weight = sum(weight)
            ) |>
  select(Animal, everything()) |>
  transmute(
            Animal = Animal,
            red = red/weight,
            green = green/weight,
            blue = blue/weight
            ) |>
  transmute(
            Animal = Animal,
            Color = rgb(red,green,blue, maxColorValue = 255)
            )
```

in the first `transmute()`, the hex code separate to rgb value between **0** to **255** and **Bias** to **weight**.
then the **weight** applied to each row by multiplying it to rgb and sum RGBs and weight grouped by `Animal` and bring the `Animal` column back (`select(Animal, everything())`), then devide RGB of each row by **weight** and finally convert RGB to hex.
there is some other ways to do this, but I think it's a good way to learn something about R.
the new_df is like this:

```
> new_df
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Animal Color  
  <chr>  <chr>  
1 Cat    #5544EE
2 Dog    #8888FF
3 Frog   #AA2A7F
>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is happening in the `strtoi()` function. I have read the manual for it and tried running by replacing the `2` and `3` in other combinations. I still can't quite understand how it works.

Comment: function named **string to integer**, as you know in the hex color `#RRGGBB` after **#** the 2nd and 3rd character is for **Red**, 4th & 5th is for **Green**, 6th & 7th belong to **Blue**, so I use `substr()` to substring the hex color to red, green and blue, and due to the hex base is 16, I use `base = 16` as next argument. if you select code from `new_df <- df |>` to end of first `transmute(Animal= Animal, ...)` and hit `ctrl`+`Enter` in RStudio you can see the result.

Comment: You can also use col2rgb() in first `transmute` like this ```transmute(Animal = Animal, as.data.frame(t(col2rgb(Colour))), weight = Bias)```

Answer (score 0):

**using `data.table`**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat.an)

cols <- c("red", "green", "blue")
dat.an[, (cols) := as.list(col2rgb(Colour)), Colour][
  , lapply(.SD, weighted.mean, w = Bias), Animal, .SDcols = cols][
  , .(Colour = rgb(red, green, blue, maxColorValue = 255)), Animal]
```

**results**

```
#    Animal  Colour
# 1:   Frog #AA2A7F
# 2:    Dog #8888FF
# 3:    Cat #5544EE
```